# CDI choosing correct scope for bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, java-ee-6, cdi

Coming from plain old DI of Spring I can't figure out how to choose scopes properly while writing with CDI.

In Spring all my services have singleton scope by default, which I suppose maps to application scope in CDI (or even @Singleton). I know for e.g. logged in user information I need to use Session scope and for e.g. form params I need request scope.

Say I have a bean that hides external service API calls. It is completely stateless. Should I put it as `@Singleton` or simply application scoped? Or let it be created on every request (possibly bad option).

Is this correct to inject everything everywhere? In Spring I create my data objects by `new`. Should I do the same in CDI or simply `@Inject` them?

Answer (score 1):

Are you only using CDI? or a Java EE 6 container?  If you have a stateless class that is used for service calls, then I would recommend using @Stateless, which is from the EJB spec (so you would need a Java EE 6 container)  It isn't a singleton, but it doesn't get created on each request either.  I believe it is more closely bound to the session, but since it is stateless, instances can be pooled and shared.  If you are only dealing with CDI, I believe Singleton matches more directly to Spring's singleton, but I would recommend using ApplicationScoped because it provides a proxy which makes serialization of beans that use it easier.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using JEE app server. Yeah, I could use Stateless that's true.

Comment: In Weld and OWB (not sure about CanDI) `@Singleton` and `@ApplicationScoped` are effectively the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Service
@Scope("prototype")
public class CustomerService 
{
......
}
```

Just add @Scope("prototype") annotation to your component.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you would need the bean to remember it's state? If you are using something like a web client, that is a better place to store state in say, session scoped managed beans (assuming jsf), or whatever equivalent for your case. On the back end server side your EJB's would be better kept as @stateless to keep overhead to a minimum and help with the 'keep it simple s..." paradigm. And in case this works, just declare @Stateless on your bean. Unless there is a reason to use a singleton, again it is better to use a stateless bean if you want to go with a Java EE container for your services.

Stateless beans are not really being recreated with every request. That is the purpose of the pool. The app server keeps a ready supply of stateless beans on hand, and if it gets busy, it will make more, and if it quiets down, it will empty some out.